# Finding a control on Dropdownlist SelectedIndexChanged in Repeater

Tags: c#, selectedindexchanged

I have a repeater control which has a `DropDownlist` and a `TextBox`.

On `selectedIndexChanged` event of the dropdown, I need to enable or disable the textbox based on the dropdown selected value.

I am able to trigger the `SelectedIndexChanged` event but not able to find the `TextBox` control inside this event.

Below is my SelectedIndexChanged event handler in codebehind.

```
    protected void ddl_userType_SelectedIndex(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ddl = (DropDownList)sender;           
    }
```

Could someone please help me achieve what I need.

Comment: show you source code (i-e complete code)

Answer (score 3):

Hope about something like this...

```
protected void ddl_userType_SelectedIndex(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;
    RepeaterItem item = ddl.Parent as RepeaterItem;    
    Textbox tb = item.FindControl("MyTextBox") as Textbox;   
}
```